# C# Named Tasks What's the proper way?

Tags: c#, multithreading, task

I am trying to work on concatenated tasks.

My idea is to have something similar to the next code, but VS marks my code as:

> > cannot convert from 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task' to 'System.Action' in Argument1

Whats the proper way to syntax this ?

```
public void startAllTasks()
{
    Task task1 = new Task(() => GetLocalDbRecords());
    Task task2 = new Task(() => CreatePlainTextFile());
    Task task3 = new Task(() => SendToWS());
    task1.ContinueWith(task2);
    task2.ContinueWith(task3);
    task1.Start();
}
```

I have my desired result by using the next code (I know I must optimize it), but my idea is to improve it by using the "ContinueWith" and one CancellationToken, but no luck yet

```
public void startAllTasks()
        {
            records = 0;
            stopFlag = false;
            tasksRunning = new Dictionary<int, bool>();
            tasksRunning.Add(1, false);
            tasksRunning.Add(2, false);
            tasksRunning.Add(3, false);
            currentStep = 0;
            while (!stopFlag)
            {
                if (currentStep == 0 && !tasksRunning[1])
                {
                    tasksRunning[1] = true;
                    Task task1 = new Task(() => this.GetLocalDbRecords());
                    task1.Start();
                }
                if (currentStep == 1 && !tasksRunning[2])
                {
                    tasksRunning[2] = true;
                    Task task2 = new Task(() => this.CreatePlainTextFile());
                    task2.Start();
                }
                if (currentStep == 3 && !tasksRunning[3])
                {
                    tasksRunning[3] = true;
                    Task task3 = new Task(() => this.SendToWS());
                    task3.Start();
                }
                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Why not `Task task1 = new Task(() => GetLocalDbRecords()).ContinueWith(x => CreatePlainTextFile()).ContinueWith(x => SendToWS());`?

Comment: Why not one task that calls the 3 methods in sequence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the proper syntax (explanation below):

```
Task task1 = new Task(() => GetLocalDbRecords());
Task task2 = new Task(() => CreatePlainTextFile());
Task task3 = new Task(() => SendToWS());
task1.ContinueWith(x => task2.Start());
task2.ContinueWith(x => task3.Start());
task1.Start();
```

Note that the `ContinueWith` method does not receive a `Task` it receives an `Action<Task>`, this `Action` is invoked after the first `Task` is complete and it will receive the first `Task` as an argument so you can use it's return value for example.

You can also use this **fluent syntax** of `Task.Factory` which also removes your need to use `Task.Start()`:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(GetLocalDbRecords)
    .ContinueWith(x => CreatePlainTextFile())
    .ContinueWith(x => SendToWS())
    .Wait();
```

In order to use a `CancellationToken` you need to use a `CancellationTokenSource` and it works like that:

*From [MSDN's Page about `Task` cancellation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537607(v=vs.110).aspx)*

> 1) Create and start a cancelable task.
>
> 2) Pass a cancellation token to your user delegate and optionally to the task instance.
>
> 3) Notice and respond to the cancellation request in your user delegate.
>
> 4) Optionally notice on the calling thread that the task was canceled.

And a code example:

```
CancellationTokenSource tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
CancellationToken token = tokenSource.Token;

Task.Factory.StartNew(GetLocalDbRecords)
    .ContinueWith(x => CreatePlainTextFile(), tokenSource.Token)
    .ContinueWith(x => SendToWS(), tokenSource.Token);

tokenSource.Cancel();
bool cancelationRequested = token.IsCancellationRequested; //Value will be true.
```

`Task`s will not stop automatically when you use `tokenSource.Cancel();` as they might run on the same `Thread` which invoked them and they must be aware of the `CancellationToken` and poll `IsCancellationRequested` if they wish to stop according to it, however, if a `Task` or its consecutive `Task`s are trying to start when the `CancellationToken` is already been requested to cancel, the `Task` or its consecutive `Task`s will not be invoked in the first place.

Also, you can use `CancellationTokenSource.CancelAfter(TimeSpan)` in order to put a timeout before cancelling.

Comment: nice response. I'm still curious about how to introduce the CancellationToken based on my 'stopFlag' variable, so when stopFlag is true the current task be stopped and therefore its pending tasks..

Comment: Added an edit to the answer with information about `CancellationToken`s.

Comment: It's important to note that Start is a code smell and that the code should not be written with unstarted tasks at all. There is no need (and there never is).